# Import external libraries and generate single file with typescript

Tags: typescript, typescript1.8

In Gulp, I use Typescript to transpile files to ES6, then Babel to generate ES5, and finally Browserify to generate 1 file with all the modules. This is my code:

```
gulp.task('scripts', function() {
    return browserify('./src/scripts/main.ts')
        .plugin(tsify, {moduleResolution: "node", target:"es5", allowJs:true, allowUnreachableCode:true"})
        .transform("babelify", {presets:["es2015"], extensions:[".ts", ".js"]})
        .bundle()
        //Pass desired output filename to vinyl-source-stream
        .pipe(source('main.js'))
        // Start piping stream to tasks!
        .pipe(gulp.dest('./dist/scripts/'));
});
```

I thought it would be nice and less error prone if I only had to rely on Typescript for all of the above. With the transpiler I tried this

```
tsc --moduleResolution "node" --module "amd"  --allowJs --outDir "out/" --allowUnreachableCode --out foo.js main.ts
```

This almost works fine, the only problem is that it doesn't import external libraries like `jquery` or `d3`. That is, if my code says `import * as d3 from "d3"`, nothing gets imported. Browserify, on the other hand, recognizes these libraries and has no trouble importing them.

What am I missing? No error is generated so I have no clue about what's going on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Browserify, on the other hand, recognizes these libraries and has no trouble importing them. 
>   What am I missing?

Please use browserify (or [webpack](https://basarat.gitbooks.io/typescript/content/docs/quick/browser.html)) for external libs.

Basically you have a file `d3.d.ts` that is the *actual* import into the context and not the `node_modules/d3/*`. So TypeScript doesn't load `node_modules/d3` for compilation output.

## More

`--allowJS` is to facilitate *your JavaScript* migration at this point. You have just discovered one of probably many pitfalls.

PS: TypeScript will most likely work fine if the node_module is itself in TypeScript as well.

Comment: Though, I now figured you can still import js modules with, for example, `import * as d3 from "../../node_modules/d3/d3.js"` and it'll work. Do you know why is that?

Comment: Yes. Because it is now loading the `js` instead of the `d3.d.ts`. However you loose the type safety of `d3.d.ts`